# Find a vector of length one that is orthogonal to U and lies in span Y.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the first component of the vector that has length one, has apositive first component, is orthogonal to  $ \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
3 \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix} $ , and lies in span{ $ \begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
1 \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix} $, $ \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix} $}

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$\textbf{v}=a\left(\begin{array}{c} 3\\1\\-1\end{array}\right)+b\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\1\\1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} 3a+b\\a+b\\-a+b\end{array}\right)$$
By orthogonality, we have
$$1(3a+b)+3(a+b)+(-1)(-a+b)=7a+3b=0$$
Hence
$$b=-\frac{7}{3}a$$
and
$$\textbf{v}=\left(\begin{array}{c} 2a/3\\-4a/3\\-10a/3\end{array}\right)=\frac{a}{3}\left(\begin{array}{c} 2\\-4\\-10\end{array}\right)$$
$$|\textbf{v}|=\frac{|a|}{3}\sqrt{4+16+100}=\frac{2\sqrt{30}}{3}|a|=1$$
Hence
$$a=\pm \frac{3}{2\sqrt{30}}$$
Since the first component is positive,
$$a=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{30}}$$
and
$$\frac{2a}{3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{30}}$$